# Nested case statement with different conditions in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below data

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeData
(
     EmpID INT,
     Designation VARCHAR(100),
     Grade CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #EmployeeData (EmpID, Designation, Grade)
VALUES (1, 'TeamLead', 'A'),
       (2, 'Manager', 'B'),
       (3, 'TeamLead', 'B'),
       (4, 'SeniorTeamLead', 'A'),
       (5, 'TeamLead', 'C'),
       (6, 'Manager', 'C'),
       (7, 'TeamLead', 'D'),
       (8, 'SeniorTeamLead', 'B')

SELECT Designation,CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT GRADE)>1 THEN 'MultiGrade' ELSE Grade END FROM 
#EmployeeData
GROUP BY Designation
```

Desired result:

```
 Designation      Grade
 --------------------------
 Manager        MultiGrade
 TeamLead       MultiGrade
 SeniorTeamLead      A
```

**Note:**

1. If designation has more than one grade then it is multigrade
2. If single grade is there then the particular grade
3. In case there is a combination with A and B then it should be A only

I tried with a query using `case` but I get this error:

> Column '#EmployeeData.Grade' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either` an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone suggest the query to fetch the desired result?

Comment: grade column in the select list which is neither part of the group by clause nor included in an aggregate function.

Comment: Hint: what are `MIN(Grade)` and `MAX(Grade)` in each case?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Not sure what the "nested" in the title refers to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you need to aggregate the columns you are not grouping by. So use `MAX` and `MIN` (as Jeroen commented).

```
SELECT Designation
  , CASE WHEN MAX(Grade) = 'B' AND MIN(Grade) = 'A' THEN 'A' WHEN MAX(Grade) <> MIN(Grade) THEN 'MultiGrade' ELSE MIN(Grade) END Grade
FROM #EmployeeData
GROUP BY Designation
ORDER BY Designation;
```

Your real world situation might be more complex, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Exactly my real example is different. But anyhow the above result it works good. Thank you so much.